# How to reflow Bootstrap span<x> with Angularjs?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

I'm new to Angularjs and have no intuition for how to do what I want.

I have a section that displays a bunch of properties.  If the model doesn't contain the property, that item is removed via AngularUi's ui-if like so.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span3" ui-if="!!model.Prop1">Prop1: {{ model.Prop1 }}</div>
    <div class="span3" ui-if="!!model.Prop2">Prop2: {{ model.Prop2 }}</div>
    <div class="span3" ui-if="!!model.Prop3">Prop3: {{ model.Prop3 }}</div>
    <div class="span3" ui-if="!!model.Prop4">Prop4: {{ model.Prop4 }}</div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is, for example, if two properties are empty, make the bootstrap spans `span6` instead.  Basically I want it to split the span12 evenly for the properties that actually have data and remove the others.  ui-if takes care of removing empty properties from the dom nicely, but now how do I adjust the `span<x>`'s?

Comment: Best to put that logic in a directive, checking to see how many props are set and changing the class that's applied to the div accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [ng-class](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angClass) or you simply interpolate the class attribute:

```html
<div class="span{{number}}" ui-if="!!model.Prop1">Prop1: {{ model.Prop1 }}</div>
```

And in controller you would do:

```js
$scope.number = 6;
```

Of course, the logic to set `$scope.number` would be more complex than just setting it, and should reside in a [Controller](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts#controller).